# How to sort an array alphabetically in a dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort the next dropdownlist with the sort () function of fixes but it doesn't work for me

The following is the dropdownlist that I try to sort alphabetically with the javascript function that loads the data

```js
function loadService() {
    const url = document.getElementById("service").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                const service = document.getElementById("ticketServiceInput");

                const arrDataSorted = data.sort((a, b) => (a.value > b.value) ? 1 : ((b.value > a.value) ? -1 : 0));

                for (let idx in arrDataSorted) {
                    if (arrDataSorted.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                        const option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.innerHTML = arrDataSorted[idx].Name;
                        option.value = arrDataSorted[idx].ServiceId;
                        service.options.add(option);                  
                    }
                }               
            }           
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group" id="ServiceDiv">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="service" for="ticketServiceInput">Service:</label>
                                    <select id="ticketServiceInput" name="service" onchange="loadSubService(); validate(this)" class="form-control form-control-use validateable" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a option</option>
                                    </select>
                                  
                                </div>
```

I don't know if I'll be executing the sort function the wrong way or what might be happening

**UPDATE:**

Try the following but no result

```
function loadService() {
    const url = document.getElementById("service").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                const service = document.getElementById("ticketServiceInput");

                const arrDataSorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
                    return a.value - b.value;
                } );



                for (let idx in arrDataSorted) {
                    if (arrDataSorted.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                        const option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.innerHTML = arrDataSorted[idx].Name;
                        option.value = arrDataSorted[idx].ServiceId;
                        service.options.add(option);                  
                    }
                }               
            }           
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: what does the data look like

Comment: I get the data from the database

Comment: Does the data from the database have strings that start with numbers? Javascript sorting of that can be problematic.

Comment: const url = document.getElementById("service").value; but the link doesn't have an id?

Comment: @LeeSalminen This is an example of the string that returns `[{"ServiceId":1,"Name":"BLACKBOARD","Content":"Software de educación,`

Comment: @Chev id corresponds to `ticketServiceInput`

Comment: Thanks, my mistake. What property in the results do you want to sort by? Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer was to change

```
const arrDataSorted = data.sort((a, b) => (a.value > b.value) ? 1 : ((b.value > a.value) ? -1 : 0));
```

to

```
const arrDataSorted = data.sort((a, b) => (a.Name > b.Name) ? 1 : ((b.Name > a.Name) ? -1 : 0));
```

After Sebastian provided his example data of

```
[{"ServiceId":1,"Name":"BLACKBOARD","Content":"Software de educación"}...]
```

it became clear he wanted to sort on the `Name` property of the Object and not the `value`.

Chev in another answer recommended using `lodash` to help with these sorting functions, which I definitely agree with. Lodash is a great tool when working with JS.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [lodash sortby](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy) for this. Nice and simple. Given the data you shared:

```
    arrDataSorted = _.sortBy(data, (x) => {
      return x.Name;
    });
```

Or use your function:

```
 let arrDataSorted = data.sort(function(a, b) {
        var nameA = a.Name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        var nameB = b.Name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        if (nameA < nameB) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
          return 1;
        }

        // names must be equal
        return 0;
    });
```